# How to login to a website and scrape data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to create a program where I can check my grades using python and I have the code to web scrape data, but I do not know how to log into this specific website. The website is https://hac.chicousd.org/LoginParent.aspx?page=Default.aspx and if you need it I can give my username and password. I have tried using requests and urllib and neither work. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: You could use Selenium for this: https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: How can I use python with that?

Comment: Well, `pip install selenium` will get you selenium and continue reading the documentation, it has python code samples to get you started. You'll be using webdriver mostly: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Try using [mechanical soup](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup). It allows you to navigate a website just like you would normally.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, a possibility is to use `selenium`, a browser manipulation tool. However, you can also use `requests.Sessions` to send a `POST` request with a payload of the email, and then a `GET` request for whatever portal page you wish to view after:

```
import requests
r = requests.Session()
payload = {'portalAccountUsername':'yoursutdentemail@school.com'}
r.post('https://hac.chicousd.org/LoginParent.aspx?page=Default.aspx', data = payload)
```

Then, with `r` instance, you can send a `GET` request to a page on the portal that is only visible to authenticated users:

```
data = r.get('https://hac.chicousd.org/some_student_only_page').text
```

Note that the keys of the `payload` dictionary must all be valid `<input>` `"name"` values from the site's HTML.

Comment: @OnkarSandhu did you try and send a `GET` request to a different page after first logging in with `r.post`? Also, insure that the keys of the dictionary match the name attributes in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use `selenium`. You also should use `time` to stop the program some seconds before to put your password. First install selenium in you command prompt `pip install selenuim` and a webdriver (here is the code for chrome `pip install chromedriver_installer`). Then you could use them in your code.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep
```

Then, you should open the web page with the web driver

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users...\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('The website address')
```

The next step is to find the name of the elements on the web page to write your username, password, and the path for the buttons

```
username = browser.find_element_by_id('portalAccountUsername')
username.send_keys('your email')

next = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]')
next.click()

password = browser.find_element_by_id('portalAccountPassword')
time.sleep(2)
password.send_keys('your password')

sing_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LoginButton"]')
sing_in.click()
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work by using selenium. It worked perfectly, thanks!